# Pics Drawing Software for Scientific Articles: Alternatives to LateX / TikZ / PGF

Tags: flowchart

Please advise alternatives to LateX / TikZ / PGF in which you can easily and quickly draw high-quality pictures (diagrams, algorithms, graphs, plots, etc.) for scientific articles.

Comment: What features & differentiators do you need? How don't those that you have listed meet your needs? What platform(s) & price range?

Comment: These programs do not meet my requirements in terms of the need to work with code. I would like to see something like Visio, but it is not as beautiful as TikZ / PGF. Price range: 0 - $ 100 per year for using a license.